# Dynamic scheduling spark job on Yarn

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm running spark on Yarn but my application keeps getting Out of Memory Exception while trying to load a large RDD even though I had dynamic scheduling set to true

...

```
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.default.parallelism", String.valueOf(cpu * 3))
```

To fix this, I had to specify the executor memory

...

```
.set("spark.driver.memory", "5g")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "30g")
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.default.parallelism", String.valueOf(cpu * 3))
```

```

but isn't the whole point of dynamic scheduling to allocate the required resources from Yarn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on YARN dynamic resource allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation):

> In Spark, dynamic resource allocation is performed on the granularity of the executor

This means it will spin up more executors, but it does not mean it will change how much memory individual executors have. If you are loading more resources into memory than a single executor can handle, spinning up more of them won't do any good.